# Como trabalhar com o git quando ha problemas na versão produção?

Tags: git

Eu tenho uma aplicação em produção que estava trabalhando em um novo modulo dentro de uma branch no meu repositório local, quando  finalizei, e apos realizar testes, fiz o merger com o master mandei pro servidor. Logo apos encontrei um problema grande na aplicação, tentei fazer um checkout direto no servidor mas não consegui por que tive problemas com o console, ai acabei usando o próprio rollback do server pra reverter.

Minha duvida é sobre qual seria a forma mas correta de trabalhar em uma situação como esta fazendo uso do git ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira que eu acho mais segura é usando `git reset --hard` e passando o hash do commit anterior ao commit com problema.

Para isso, primeiro descubra o hash do commit, usando `git reflog`, que vai gerar algo assim como saída:

```
git reflog
1234567 HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Merge branch local/nome-da-branch into local/master
2345678 HEAD@{1}: commit: alguma alteracao qualquer
3456789 HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

Neste caso, o último merge foi o 1234567, então queremos voltar para o 2345678, então basta executar:

`git reset --hard 2345678`

Também pode usar o número do `HEAD`, assim:
`git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

Comment: Legal, isso vai me ajudar muito, agora vejo que era muito fácil resolver meu problema. Muito Obrigado

Comment: sim funciona bem, já tive de fazer alguns rollbacks :D  não esqueça de marcar a pergunta se ela ajudou a resolver o problema